# PHP Get array key value depends on another array key

Tags: php, arrays

OK, here is the method,

I have an array called post

this one has these keys:
id,title,description

i'm storing all my ids,titles and descriptions in those keys.

Now i work on my post titles,

i have another array called keywords

Thanks to @Dagon, i could check my keywords on my title array , so if the title contains some of these keywords i return those titles.

now my question is :

my returned titles that only contained some of the keywords i want to get its id and its description

**EDIT**

for example ,

```
$lang_name = array("php","html");

$languages = array(
"id" => array("1","2","3"),
"lang"=>array("php","html","css"),
"version"=>array("PHP5","HTML5","CSS3")
);


  foreach($lang_name as $lang){
    if(in_array($lang,$languages['lang'])){
      echo $lang."<br>";
      // now i want to get the version and id of the languages for php and html values
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should post the smallest amount of code possible to duplicate the issue.

Comment: We are here to help you fix the errors of your code. **Not** to write it for you. Please, show what have you done so far and at what point are you stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lang_name = array("php","html");

$languages = array(
    "id" => array("1","2","3"),
    "lang"=>array("php","html","css"),
    "version"=>array("PHP5","HTML5","CSS3")
);
```

The script to find ID and VERSION:

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach( $languages['lang'] as $key => $lng )
{
    if ( in_array( $lng, $lang_name ) )
    {
        $new_arr[$lng] = array( 'id' => $languages['id'][$key],
                                'ver' => $languages['version'][$key]
            );
    }

}

print_r( $new_arr );
```

And the result:

```
Array
(
    [php] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [ver] => PHP5
        )

    [html] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [ver] => HTML5
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($lang_name as $index =>  $lang){
  if(in_array($lang,$languages['lang'])){
   echo $lang."<br>";
   // now i want to get the version and id of the languages for php and html values
   echo  $languages['id'][$index]. ' : '. $languages['version'][$index].'<br>';
  }
}
```